# JavaScript: handle onclick, onmouseover and onmouseout functions in an external JavaScript file ONLY

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onmouseover, onmouseout

So I have to display plain ole tooltips in various situations.  I have to deal with canceling the default behavior of URL links using an onclick event, show the tooltip on a mouseover event and hide the tooltip on a mouseout event.  I am going to include all my HTML, CSS and JavaScript code so far.  This has to be done only in an external JavaScript file (i.e. can't change the HTML or the CSS at all).  I also cannot use innerHTML (must use JavaScript best practices).  I have tried to write the code to the best of my ability (I am really new to JavaScript).  None of the functions work at the moment.  I have to have exactly 3 functions and they are laid out in the correct manner (I think) in the Javascript.  Ok, enough of my babbling here's the code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tool Tips</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Tool Tips
</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randy_Rhoads" class="tip">Randy Rhoads
<span> Randy Rhoads blah blah blah</span></a> 
ut augue risus.
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ty_Tabor" class="tip">Ty Tabor
<span> Ty Tabor blah blah blah</span></a> 
cras pharetra. 
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Timmons" class="tip">Andy Timmons
<span> Andy Timmons blah blah blah</span></a> proin mattis, s auctor. 
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Bonamassa" class="tip">Joe Bonamassa
<span> Joe Bonamassa blah blah blah</span></a> Duis ac est quam.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* styles the anchors that have tooltips*/
.tip {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #333;
    cursor: help;
    position: relative;
    color: #600;
}

/* hides all tooltips by default on page load */
.tip span {
    display: none;
/* none of these matter now because the tooltips are hidden */
/* when JS unhides the tooltips, these will already be in place */
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #333;
}

/* applied by JS to show tips */
.tip span.showTip {
    display: block;
}

/* applied by JS to hide tips */
.tip span.hideTip {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
// *** Use JavaScript best practices ***
// *** This means that the HTML and the CSS are not to be edited at all ***
// *** No <script> tags are to be added to the HTML ***
// *** No inline JavaScript is to be added to the HTML ***
// *** The CSS is to be left alone, no changes are allowed ***

// Step 1: Create the ONLOAD event so that the function prepareTips() runs once the page has finished loading
window.onload = prepareTips;

// Step 2: Declare the prepareTips() function
function prepareTips() {

    // Step 3: Scan the document looking for all anchor tags
    var arrAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    // Step 4: Handle browsers that DON'T SUPPORT EITHER CSS OR JAVASCRIPT. 
    // *** If this is the case, the tooltips are hidden and the links open to the Wikipedia pages ***
    if(!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;

    //*** If the browser supports both CSS and JavaScript, the prepareTips() function does the following: ***

    // Step 5: Loop thru all the anchor tags and assigning the events to be handled for all of the links/tooltips
    for (var i=0; i<arrAnchors.length; i++) {

        // Step 6: Bind the showTip() function to the <span> tags' MOUSEOVER event
         arrAnchors.onmouseover = showTip;

        // Step 7: Bind the hideTip() function to the <span> tags' MOUSEOUT event
         arrAnchors.onmouseout = hideTip;

        // Step 8: Bind the showTip() function to the onclick event
        arrAnchors.onclick = showTip;
     }          
}

// *** NOTE: Tooltip triggers are anchor tags and contain the class "tip" ***
// *** NOTE: The .tip class is applied without the use of JavaScript ***
// *** NOTE: The .tip span class formats the tooltip spans but hides them by default.  This is applied without JavaScript ***

// Step 9: Create a separate function called showtip()
function showTip() {

    // Step 10: When an onclick event for a link happens, cancel the default behavior of the link.
    // *** The browser does not go to the URL value contained in the HREF ***
    // *** So the links do nothing when clicked (i.e. return false) instead of going to the Wikipedia page of the guitar player ***
      var arrLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

          for (var i=0; i<arrLinks.length; i++) {
            arrLinks[i].onlick = function() {
            return false;
        }

    // Step 11: The showtip() function changes the anchor class to ".tip span.showTip" located in the CSS file 
    // *** The .tip span.showTip class in the CSS file simply overrides the display property, showing the tooltip span as a block element ***
    // *** This is to be applied using JavaScript (no other properties of the .tip span.showTip will be changed) ***
          arrLinks[i].className === 'showTip';

    // Step 12: Show the associated tooltip when an onmouseover event for a link occurs
    // *** The tooltip that is displayed is the text between the <span>Tooltip text here</span> tags ***
    // *** For example: The tooltip to be displayed when the mouse is hovered over the Randy Rhoads link is: "Randy Rhoads blah blah blah" ***
    // *** The <span> is a child of the anchor (<a>) tags ***
    // *** This means they can be accessed in CSS with a descendant selector .tip span ***
          var tooltip = arrLinks[i].setAttribute('title', arrLinks[i].childName['span'].nodeValue);
     }
}

// Step 13: Create a separate function called hideTip()
function hideTip() {

    // Step 14: The showtip() function changes the anchor class to ".tip span.hideTip" located in the CSS file 
    // *** The .tip span.hideTip class in the CSS file sets the display property back to none, hiding the tooltip ***
      var hideTips = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    // Step 15: Hide the associated tooltip when the mouseout event for the links occurs.
    // *** The <span> is a child of the anchor (<a>) tags ***
    // *** This means they can be accessed in CSS with a descendant selector .tip span ***
      hideTips[i].className === 'hideTip';
}
```

Comment: Is this actual JavaScript code? The stars `*` are invalidating the syntax. Also, `===` is a comparison operator, not the assignment operator. Even more, post the error message you get when you run the code (check your browsers JavaScript error console).

Comment: Sorry the extra stars were added when I applied bold to the text using the text editor.  The only error message I get is:  "TypeError: function prepareTips does not always return a value"  I think there is a lot of wrong code in here but I'm not sure how to go about fixing these errors.

Comment: I don't get it that somebody wants to reinvent the wheel again. When you google on javascript tooltip solutions you will find what you want. Also, try to use jQuery, it will make your life allot easier and there anough plugins for it available.

Comment: Can't use jQuery yet...this is for a class...we haven't studied jQuery...I am a complete newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick glance would suggest your problem is that you `return false` when a browser can't use JS/CSS, but you don't `return true` when it does. This results in the problem you're having. I'm guessing you're supposed to do something (and not just `return false`) when it can't handle JS/CSS, but you were trying to return as a placeholder.

Side note: if a browser doesn't support JS...how is it supposed to execute JS to determine if it supports it or not?

Comment: Very good points :)  All I know is that in class, my teacher says to put if(!document.getElementByID) or something like it and return false.  That is the only way I know

Comment: @HoppedUpDesigns Your teacher is most likely an ignorant novice that is only capable of doing what is stated in a book written by an equally amateur author. You'll just have to do what I did in college: do it the way they show you in class, and then do it the right way when working on your own projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're talking about to bring text on tooltip from span text and you're not getting the text into span for display on tooltip of anchor tag.
You're not getting span text into title bar and you've not even mentioned function properly in your onload function. You'll get better idea about your little mistakes and corrections on below code. Comment your js code and put this js code.

```
// *** Use JavaScript best practices ***
// *** This means that the HTML and the CSS are not to be edited at all ***
// *** No <script> tags are to be added to the HTML ***
// *** No inline JavaScript is to be added to the HTML ***
// *** The CSS is to be left alone, no changes are allowed ***

// Step 1: Create the ONLOAD event so that the function prepareTips() runs once the page has finished loading
window.onload = prepareTips;

// Step 2: Declare the prepareTips() function
function prepareTips() {

    // Step 3: Scan the document looking for all anchor tags
    var arrAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    // Step 4: Handle browsers that DON'T SUPPORT EITHER CSS OR JAVASCRIPT. 
    // *** If this is the case, the tooltips are hidden and the links open to the Wikipedia pages ***
    if(!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;

    //*** If the browser supports both CSS and JavaScript, the prepareTips() function does the following: ***

    // Step 5: Loop thru all the anchor tags and assigning the events to be handled for all of the links/tooltips
    for (var i=0; i<arrAnchors.length; i++) {

        // Step 6: Bind the showTip() function to the <span> tags' MOUSEOVER event
         arrAnchors.onmouseover = showTip();

        // Step 7: Bind the hideTip() function to the <span> tags' MOUSEOUT event
         arrAnchors.onmouseout = hideTip();

        // Step 8: Bind the showTip() function to the onclick event
        arrAnchors.onclick = showTip();
     }          
}

// *** NOTE: Tooltip triggers are anchor tags and contain the class "tip" ***
// *** NOTE: The .tip class is applied without the use of JavaScript ***
// *** NOTE: The .tip span class formats the tooltip spans but hides them by default.  This is applied without JavaScript ***

// Step 9: Create a separate function called showtip()
function showTip() {

    // Step 10: When an onclick event for a link happens, cancel the default behavior of the link.
    // *** The browser does not go to the URL value contained in the HREF ***
    // *** So the links do nothing when clicked (i.e. return false) instead of going to the Wikipedia page of the guitar player ***
      var arrLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

          for (var i=0; i<arrLinks.length; i++) {
            arrLinks[i].onlick = function() {
            return false;
        }

    // Step 11: The showtip() function changes the anchor class to ".tip span.showTip" located in the CSS file 
    // *** The .tip span.showTip class in the CSS file simply overrides the display property, showing the tooltip span as a block element ***
    // *** This is to be applied using JavaScript (no other properties of the .tip span.showTip will be changed) ***
          arrLinks[i].className === 'showTip';

    // Step 12: Show the associated tooltip when an onmouseover event for a link occurs
    // *** The tooltip that is displayed is the text between the <span>Tooltip text here</span> tags ***
    // *** For example: The tooltip to be displayed when the mouse is hovered over the Randy Rhoads link is: "Randy Rhoads blah blah blah" ***
    // *** The <span> is a child of the anchor (<a>) tags ***
    // *** This means they can be accessed in CSS with a descendant selector .tip span ***
          arrLinks[i].setAttribute('title', arrLinks[i].childNodes[1].innerHTML);
     }
}

// Step 13: Create a separate function called hideTip()
function hideTip() {

    // Step 14: The showtip() function changes the anchor class to ".tip span.hideTip" located in the CSS file 
    // *** The .tip span.hideTip class in the CSS file sets the display property back to none, hiding the tooltip ***
      var hideTips = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    // Step 15: Hide the associated tooltip when the mouseout event for the links occurs.
    // *** The <span> is a child of the anchor (<a>) tags ***
    // *** This means they can be accessed in CSS with a descendant selector .tip span ***
      hideTips[i].className === 'hideTip';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using "css" and "javascript" to show toolltip and hide tooltip. Its very easy way to display tooltip on url in html. Just change few lines in your code which i wrote below. You dont need to use css and javascript.

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randy_Rhoads" title="go to randy rhoad wikipedia  page">Randy Rhoads
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ty_Tabor" title="go to Tv Tabor wikipedia page">Ty Tabor
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Timmons" title="go to Andy Timmons wikipedia page">Andy Timmons
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Bonamassa" title="go to Joe Bonamassa wikipedia page">Joe Bonamassa
```

Comment: I can't change the HTML or CSS at all (see the comments at the top of the Javascript code).  Everything has to be done in an external Javascript file.